# Why does copy_to_user fail after process forked?

Tags: linux, fork, kernel-module, copy-on-write, page-fault

I'm writing a kernel module that would write some data to user space buffer via `copy_to_user`. However, I found that `copy_to_user` always fails (returns non-zero) after the process forks. (`copy_to_user` works fine if I don't fork the process.) `copy_to_user` was called right after forked and I've used `access_ok` to check accessibility of the destination address.

I'm aware that after forking, child process will share meory with parent process due to copy-on-write mechanism. So I assume the reason that `copy_to_user` failed after fork might due to COW page fault.

My questions are,

1. Is my assumption about COW mechanism causing `copy_to_user` failed true?
2. If above is true, why didn't kernel handle page fault? Or What should I do to make `copy_to_user` work after process fork?

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: "I've used `access_ok` to check accessibility of the destination address..." - Don't confuse  yourself: successful call to `access_ok` just means that the address doesn't belong to the kernel and **may** belong to user, if mapped. Successful `access_ok` doesn't confirm that the address can be accessed in the particular address space.